# transform: perspective не применяется на safari

Tags: html, css

Знатоки, появилась проблема. Вывожу блок со свойством transform: perspective, и на айфонах блок просто-напросто не выводится. Интернет перелопатил, так и не нашел решения( Буду рад любой подсказке

```
<div class="sale_15">
                <span class="sale_15_text">скидка 15%</span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.sale_15_text{
    font-size: 64px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #fff;

}
.sale_15{
    background: #FF4800;
    border-radius: 26px;

    width: 505px;
    height: 103px;
    margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center; 
    transform: perspective(278px) rotateY(10deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство `perspective` на desktop`e Safari с v4 Реализовано с префиксом поставщика: -webkit- c v9 Полная поддержка. На мобилках Safari on iOS с v2 Реализовано с префиксом поставщика: -webkit- c v9 Полная поддержка.

Попробуй добавить префикс.. И уточни на [canuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=transform) поддерживает ли твоя версия сафари..

```css
.sale_15_text {
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
}

.sale_15 {
  background: #FF4800;
  border-radius: 26px;
  width: 505px;
  height: 103px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(278px) rotateY(10deg);
  /* Safari & Chrome */
  -moz-transform: perspective(278px) rotateY(10deg);
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform: perspective(278px) rotateY(10deg);
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-transform: perspective(278px) rotateY(10deg);
  /* Opera */
  transform: perspective(278px) rotateY(10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="sale_15">
  <span class="sale_15_text">скидка 15%</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а если блок обрезается наполовину https://prnt.sc/qtYzGnmgawkX это можно сказать о несовместимости transform: perspective с версией браузера?

Comment: @TinturSoft ссылка не работает.